# Exception when using MySqlBackup.NET to export database

Tags: c#, mysql, mysqlbackup.net

I used the [following code](http://mysqlbackupnet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Documentation%20for%20MySqlBackup.NET%20V1.5) for backup the MYSQL database.

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string file = "D:\\backup.sql";
        //string conn = "server=localhost;user=root;pwd=qwerty;database=test;";
        String str = @"server=192.168.1.219;database=abc;userid=sha;password='123';";
        MySqlBackup mb = new MySqlBackup(str);
        mb.ExportInfo.FileName = file;
        mb.Export();
    }
```

my stack trace is following -

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in MySqlBackup.dll
System.Transactions Critical: 0 : <TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Critical"><TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/TraceCodes/System/ActivityTracing/2004/07/Reliability/Exception/Unhandled</TraceIdentifier><Description>Unhandled exception</Description><AppDomain>TestAppMysqlDBConnect.vshost.exe</AppDomain><Exception><ExceptionType>System.NullReferenceException, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType><Message>Object reference not set to an instance of an object.</Message><StackTrace>   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlBackup.ExportExecute()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlBackup.Export()
   at TestAppMysqlDBConnect.Form1.button2_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\Shashika\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\TestAppMysqlDBConnect\TestAppMysqlDBConnect\Form1.cs:line 52
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   ..
```

But there is a exception and is says there is a null references exception. when i pass the data to the database through the C# program. it was successfully inserted there were no exception. this exception only occur in when i try to backup the database through the C# program. i used 2 Dll files that was in above link. those are - 
      MySql.Data.dll
      MySqlBackup.dll

I can not solve this exception. Please help.

[image: Exception]

Comment: Please include a *text copy* of the stack trace. It is shown in the lower right frame.

Comment: @pst - I think i include it now

Comment: @pst - Sorry for the late. i think this is what you want. isn't it ?

Comment: Yup. It's not very useful here - but it does show the exception comes from somewhere (directly) within MySqlBackup.Export.

Comment: @pst - thank you. i think i solved it now. MySqlBackup.dll need another dll called Ionic.Zip. i included it to my program and problem was solved. thank you again. because your comment help to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this function (Don't forget that you have to add MySqlBackup.dll to your project reference):

```
public void Backup()
    {
        try
        {
            // Backup...
            DateTime Time = DateTime.Now;
            year = Time.Year;
            month = Time.Month;
            day = Time.Day;
            hour = Time.Hour;
            minute = Time.Minute;
            second = Time.Second;
            millisecond = Time.Millisecond;

            //Save file to Path with the current date as a filename
            string path;
            path = txb_Path.Text + year + "-" + month + "-" + day + "--" + hour + "-" + minute + "-" + second + ".sql";
            string file = path;
            using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand())
                {
                    using (MySqlBackup mb = new MySqlBackup(cmd))
                    {
                        cmd.Connection = conn;
                        conn.Open();
                        mb.ExportToFile(file);
                        conn.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
            //Done----
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error , unable to backup!" + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```